# (Swift 3) - How to include animations in custom UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, timer, uikit, core-graphics

I have a `UIView` subclass called `View`, in which I want a "ripple" to move outwards from wherever the user double clicks (as well as preforming other drawing functions). Here is the relevant part of my `draw` method, at present:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    for r in ripples {
        r.paint()
    }
}
```

This is how `r.paint()` is implemented, in class `Ripple`:

```
func paint() {
    let c = UIColor(white: CGFloat(1.0 - (Float(iter))/100), alpha: CGFloat(1))
    print(iter, " - ",Float(iter)/100)
    c.setFill()
    view.fillCircle(center: CGPoint(x:x,y:y), radius: CGFloat(iter))
}
```

`iter` is supposed to be incremented every 0.1 seconds by a `Timer` which is started in the constructor of `Ripple`:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: move)
```

`move` is implemented as follows:

```
func move(_ timer: Timer) {
    while (tier<100) {
        iter += 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

What is supposed to happen is that every 0.1 seconds when the timer fires, it will increment `iter` and tell the `View` to repaint, which it will then do using the `Ripple.paint()` method, which uses `iter` to determine the color and radius of the circle.

However, as revealed using `print` statements, what happens instead is that the `Timer` fires all 100 times before the redraw actually takes place. I have tried dealing with this by replacing `DispatchQueue.main.async` with `DispatchQueue.main.sync`, but this just made the app hang. What am I doing wrong? If this is just not the right way to approach the problem, how can I get a smooth ripple animation (which involves a circle which grows while changing colors) to take place while the app can still preform other functions such as spawning more ripples? (This means that multiple ripples need to be able to work at once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with `CABasicAnimation` and custom `CALayer`, like that:

```
class MyLayer : CALayer
{
    var iter = 0

    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool
    {
        let result = super.needsDisplay(forKey: key)
        return result || key == "iter"
    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        ctx.fill(self.bounds)
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
        NSLog("Drawing, \(iter)")
    }
}

class MyView : UIView
{
    override class var layerClass: Swift.AnyClass {
        get {
            return MyLayer.self
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let myview = MyView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myview.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(myview)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "iter")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 100
        animation.duration = 10.0
        myview.layer.add(animation, forKey: "MyIterAnimation")
        (myview.layer as! MyLayer).iter = 100
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will be sure to try this when I get back to my computer

Comment: Will the view know to reload each time the animation changes `iter`?

Comment: You have to place all your drawing code into MyLayer draw(ctx) function. When you launch the app you will see in log when your MyLayer will get drawn, it will be done for each rendering call of animation, with the corresponding 'iter' value from animation.values array at the current time moment. Read more about CAKeyframeAnimation, maybe you'll switch to interpolated function which calculates value instead of array of values.

Comment: yeah I saw CABasicAnimation which looks useful; do you think that would work for me?

Comment: Yes, why not... fromValue = 0, toValue = 100. But BasicAnimation can interpolate values as floats, consider to change iter type to float so your animation will be more smooth.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to get this to work. Is there any way I can animate properties of objects other than the layer itself? For instance, what would I do if I wanted `iter` to be a property of the `MyView` object? I tried moving the variable and adding a reference to the view in `MyLayer`, and setting the key path to `myview.iter`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `CAAnimation` works only in conjunction with `CALayer`. During animation your view and it's actual layer remains having `iter === 100`. And animation happens on other instance of `MyLayer`, `presentationLayer` of `myview.layer`.

Answer (score 0):

Custom UIView like AlertView with Animation for **Swift 3 and Swift 4**

You can use a extension:

```
extension UIVIew{
  func customAlertView(frame: CGRect, message: String, color: UIColor, startY: CGFloat, endY: CGFloat) -> UIVIew{

     //Adding label to view
     let label = UILabel()
     label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height:70)
     label.textAlignment = .center
     label.textColor = .white
     label.numberOfLines = 0
     label.text = message
     self.addSubview(label)
     self.backgroundColor = color

     //Adding Animation to view
     UIView.animate(withDuration:0.5, delay: 0, options: 
     [.curveEaseOut], animations:{
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: startY, width: frame.width, height: 64)
        }) { _ in
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 4, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                 self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: endY, width: frame.width, height:64)
           }, completion: {_ in
               self.removeFromSuperview()
           })
        }
     return self
  }
```

And you can use it un your class. This example **startY** is when you have a navigationController:

```
class MyClassViewController: UIViewController{

      override func viewDidLoad(){
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.view.addSubView(UIView().addCustomAlert(frame: self.view.frame, message: "No internet connection", color: .red, startY:64, endY:-64))
      }
}
```